# Failure in starting ftp service

Tags: ftp

I am using redhat 6.7.When I tried to start or stop the services these errors happen.

```
service vsftpd stop
Shutting down vsftpd:                                      [FAILED]
[root@PHY-HUB_TrfGen_VSAT vsftpd]# service vsftpd start
Starting vsftpd for vsftpd:                                [FAILED]
```

This is the content of my `vsftpd.conf` file

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

why this is occuring and how to fix this,i have no idea

Comment: Did you check in the logs for errors?

Comment: I stopped xinetd then restarted vsftpd ..now it is working..thanks